# IF condition won't work on a button inside a form

Tags: javascript, html

i am looking to make the site i am working on responsive.I have a bar which contains a logo, a search bar and a few other buttons.What i am trying to do is using media queries to hide the search bar on mobile and activate it with a button, but i can't get it to work. Here is my form code :

```js
function resize() {
  if ($(window).width() < 1105) {
    alert("Hello World!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("formular").submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="cautare-test.php" method="post" id="formular">
  <input type="text" name="search" id="bara-cautare" placeholder="Press Enter to search!">
  <button id="test" type="button" onclick="resize()"><img src="pictures\buton_cautare.png"></button>
</form>
```

My issue is that at a width higher than 1105, the form is submitted, but at a resolution lower than that, there is no alert box when pressing the button.Thank you in advance for the help, and i'd really like to hear other solutions for responsive design.

Comment: Instead doing that, use css media queries to hide / unhide buttons.

Comment: Your code works for me, so long as you remember to include jquery in the page.   Media queries are usually a more convenient way to  respond to screen size, though.

Comment: Works for me. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: i'm using media queries as well, but would there be any possibility to use css to reactivate the search bar with a button?

Comment: @TakeDown if you don't want the form to submit under 1105, then hide the button with css so no one can click on it. As for activating search bar with button, you will have to add some details on what you mean

Comment: Why you're loading an entire heavy and old library (jQuery) just for a `window.innerWidth`?

Comment: well i am using jquery to load some html files into the main page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to use media queries, and a minimum of javascript, to accomplish what you're describing. (The JS here is used only to toggle the "show" classname on the bar. I used jQuery here for convenience, since you had some in your question, but the same can be done in vanilla JS.)  You'll need to "Expand snippet" below to see the size-responsiveness:

```js
$('#btn').on("click",function() {
  $('#bar').toggleClass("show")
});
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1105px) {
  #bar {display:none}       /* Hide the bar on small screens... */
  #bar.show {display:block} /* ...unless the user asked to show it */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1105px) {
   #btn {display:none}      /* Hide the button on large screens */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar">This is the search bar, which you want to hide on smaller screens</div>

<button id="btn">This is the "show the search bar" button, which should only be visible on smaller screens</button>
```

Comment: is there any difference between the jquery link that you are using and this one: `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js` ?

Comment: thank you for you answer, this method worked wonders. Now i just need to make it visually apealling.Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped!  To answer your question, jQuery 3 does have some breaking changes compared to version 2, but TBH the reason I chose the version I did here is because it's the latest that the SO snippet tool has a quicklink for; in real life use the most current version unless you have old code that doesn't work with the latest.

Answer (score 1):

Your code Works fine if jquery is added. Maybe you forgot to add it or don't want to use it. You then will need to add jquery or change your jquery method into vanillaJs `window.innerWidth`

```js
function resize() {
  if (window.innerWidth  < 1105) {
    alert("Hello World!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("formular").submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="cautare-test.php" method="post" id="formular">
  <input type="text" name="search" id="bara-cautare" placeholder="Press Enter to search!">
  <button id="test" type="button" onclick="resize()"><img src="pictures\buton_cautare.png"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: i am putting the code in  a menu bar, and use javascript to add it to my page. that page has jquerry added.Could that be the reason?

Comment: If you are loading the script before jquery it could be the reason

Comment: @TakeDown Have you taken a look into the console? It would tell you the reason for it not working _explicitly_.

Comment: there is nothing in the console.

Comment: @TakeDown Then see what `console.log($(window).width() < 1105);` before the `if` statement reveals.